# Verb for subtracting the mean?

Tags: terminology

Is there a verb for removing the mean or DC component of a signal? I am trying to name a flag for doing just that.

"Normalize" can mean many things, so I don't think that would be a good choice.

Comment: .."DC Blocking"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've heard this referred to as *demeaning* a signal, or applying a *DC notch* (or, in some more hardware-related domains, a *DC block*). More generally, it might be called just *highpass filtering* the signal to remove the DC component.

Comment: That's a demeaning way to refer to it! ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I've heard the word *centering* for setting the mean of a signal to 0.

Answer (score 3):

I've heard this called **detrending**. Although DC removal is a subset of what this means, [the Mathworks refers to it](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/detrending-data.html) in their `detrend` function:

```
The MATLAB® function detrend subtracts the mean or a best-fit line 
(in the least-squares sense) from your data. If your data contains 
several data columns, detrend treats each data column separately.
```

Comment: Peter, I don't believe removal of mean is 'de-trending'. As you of course know the mean simply removes the DC/constant component, however, the de-*trending* removes the uber low frequency components. (Yes I think MATLAB's usage of the verb is wrong. :-) )

Comment: @Mohammad: Agreed it's not quite right, but it is the way I've heard it used.

Comment: Peter, yeah, the terminology can get muddied up sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential candidate:

"Zero-DC-ing the signal"

Answer (score 0):

A seldomly-used term is **symmetrization**, with accounts for removing a central tendency value (could be the average, the median, the midrange, depending on the loss function to minimize).

References:

- [Algorithms for data symmetrization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103190/algorithms-for-data-symmetrization)